# GSP/Groovy - g:each with array of objects

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I'm trying to use `g:each` tag at a map but GSP don't recognize it.

The code is:

```
    if(previousQuestions == null)
    {
        previousQuestions = []
    }
    def obj = AnimaisTreeMap.get(curNode)

    previousQuestions.push('question':obj.nodeDescription, 'answer': getDescOptionAnswer(optionAnswered))
```

The g:each tag is:

```
<g:each in="${previousQuestions}" var="row" status="i">
    <div>
        <label>${row.question}</label>
        <label>${row.answer}</label>                            
    </div>
    <br/>
</g:each>
```

The output is:

```
[{question=vive na água, answer=Não}, {question=tem listras, answer=Sim}]
```

As far as I know the object that g:each reads may be at JSON format "property:value" but my object is "property=value"

How could I fix it?

**UPDATED**

After seeing [this link](http://ldaley.com/post/627158024/forwardingchaining-and-models-in-grails), I found the solution. The problem itself was with "forward" function, where I passed "previousQuestions" to another action. Instead of "params", the correct way is "model".

```
        forward(action:'index', model: [curNode: nextNode.id,
                                        previousNode: curNode, 
                                        curQuestion: curQuestion,
                                        previousQuestions: answersTrace])
```

When I need to recover "previousQuestions", I must use "request" injected object at controller. After this, my code was OK

[1](http://ldaley.com/post/627158024/forwardingchaining-and-models-in-grails): this link

Comment: show your `g.each` tag

Comment: `previousQuestions = []` this is NOT a map

Comment: @injecteer I've just added the code. I correted the title too, because is an array of objects instead

Comment: show also, how the controller action returns/renders the model. btw, where do you the the "output" you've shown? in the console?

Comment: @injecteer I printed with "log.info"

Comment: just above your <g:each try two things ${previousQuestions} and ${previousQuestions.getClass()}.

Comment: @injecteer If I try to print the object at GSP, nothing is printed. The class type is java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be adding two maps each time you call `push()`. Try creating each map you want to add to your array of maps, instead of just passing separate key value pairs.

I believe this is what you want:

```
previousQuestions.push(['question':obj.nodeDescription, 
                        'answer': getDescOptionAnswer(optionAnswered)])
```

Comment: same result...I've also tried the following

    def singleItem = new LinkedHashMap()
    singleItem.question = obj.nodeDescription
    singleItem.answer = getDescOptionAnswer(optionAnswered)
    previousQuestions.push(singleItem)

Comment: your looking at things very complex def singleItem=[:] would do the same. you need to look at the class of object being sent as above try .getClass in the gsp and also in controller do they differ ? if so it may be how you are rending the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//This is a far better way of checking null strings 
//shorter and also checks for '' as well as null
if(!previousQuestion)  {
   previousQuestions = []
} else {
   //this segment you have not provided so as a test ensure it 
   //matches List element above that you have declared - take a look at console
   println "this is probably your issue ${previousQuestions.getClass()} what is class here ????"
}

def obj = AnimaisTreeMap.get(curNode)

// generate a map on the fly good for iterations, 
// even though this is not iterated.

previousQuestions << ['questions': obj.nodeDescription as String, 
'answer':  getDescOptionAnswer(optionAnswered) as String]

//within genrated map above the elements have been converted to as String 
// Because you have not given the workings of getDescriptionAnswer
// in theory you should not need  as String this is just for testing

render (view: 'something', model: [previousQuestions:previousQuestions])
```